# Visual Studio C# project - C++ Breakpoint issue yet debugging still partially works

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I am currently working on a C# project which has a C++/CLi wrapper over some native C++ code. I debug this project by attaching it to a process (I don't have another choice, so I can't workaround the problem I'm about to mention).

(OS is Windows 7 Pro, with Visual Studio 2013 with, I believe (will check later), the full package).

Debugging (both native and managed 4.5 .NET code) worked fine till I made some change, or possibly hit some accidental shortcut (no idea what I did, tbh, it must have been at the end of the day and I didn't notice immediately, but I don't recall having done anything unusual).

Here's how it is now :

- C++ breakpoints don't get hit anymore, and have the following message when hovering above them : 
  "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.
  Possible causes include : conditional compilation, compiler optimization, or ..."
- C++/CLi breakpoints have the same indication when I hover over them, and don't get hit either.
- C# breakpoints work fine.

**BUT** if I attach my process and debug and I hit a C# breakpoint, I can then step into C++/CLi code ***and the debugger will see the objects being manipulated***. I can look at variables, and see their values and their updates. I can even step into C++ code, but in that case the debugger can't look at the objects values and states.

Here are the things tried/found out so far :

-Checked that the dlls were being properly generated and copied (it is the case, and the pdb files are also generated on every build).

-The debug module reports nothing unusual. All symbols are indicated to be loaded in the project files.

-Native code debugging is selected both when attaching process, and in startup project properties.

-Code optimisation is off. So are the Legacy Managed Code options.

-Have tried reverting to last functional commit (two days ago), but no dice. This would perhaps indicate that this is compilation or debugger configuration problem. Or perhaps a bug.

-Tried cleaning rebuilding every solution involved, one by one.

-Tried restarting Visual Studio, then the machine.

-I have a Memory Access Violation in my C++ code, with no particular link to the issue here, **BUT** when debugging, the debugger **STILL** pointed out the line in my code that was causing the issue, even though it supposedly can't link the C++ source to the running process.

-Only one instance of the process running (yet for some reason, I can't see the grayed-out .vshost.exe version of that process anymore. That is the only other change I've noticed since I encoutered the breakpoint issue).

This issue has baffled me the past day, as well as some considerably more experienced colleagues (one of them in particular being very experienced with various versions of Visual Studio since the early 2000s).

Any ideas ? From what I've seen, the breakpoint message isn't all that uncommon (my colleagues had encountered and solved it before), but this slightly different take is rather peculiar, and seems to be harder to track down.

I mean, since it's still possible to debug, and Visual Studio doesn't indicate that the source files and the executed code are different (it did before when I forgot to build before running and attaching process), it would appear to be the exact same code and VS seems to at least partially recognise that...

Comment: can you not add this line of code to your project when debugging and then select from the popup the code and or process you want to debug.. making sure you have breakpoints in the C++ code behind.. I know it works with C# but have never tried it from C# to a different framework / code base... `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't really answer why or in what way my settings appear to have changed. Nor does it change the way the debugger currently is working for me.

Comment: After some poking around, it turns out my 'Managed Compatibility Mode' settings wasn't always correctly set when attaching to the process. Which is strange, because I thought VS kept a tab on it. Ah well, it's solved, anyway.